# Filtering Subreport data on a Winforms report

Tags: winforms, reporting, service, subreport

I am using Winforms Reporting Services (RDLC) to generate a report that has a subreport.
My problem is the subreport isn't being filtered by the parent ID.

A simple example of the data model might be a Department which contains Employees.

In the report I want to show all Departments and have a subreport to show the Employees that belong to that Department.

I created a Dataset with two DataTables (Department and Employee).  I created a relationship between the two Tables using the DepartmentId column.

In the Form I Fill each table using the appropriate Fill commands.  I first fill the Department table then fill the Employee table, i.e. Select * From Deparment and Select * from Employee.

Now for the actual RDLC's:
The Department rdlc uses the Deparment datasource and shows information about the department.  I dropped a subreport control on this rdlc and set up the properties.  I am passing a ReportProperty to the subreport which is the Field!DepartmentId.

In the Employee rdlc I added the Employee datasource and created a filter on Property!DepartmentId.

When I run the report I can cycle through each Department but the subreport does not show.  If I remove the Filter from the Employee datasource the subreport shows but displays all of the employees.

In the Form itself I am handling the SubProcessing evert and adding the Employee datasource to the report.

Any ideas on how to link the Subreport data to the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the ID from the parent to the sub-report as a parameter and then filter the table in the sub-report based on that parameter value.

[MSDN - Configuring Subreports and Drillthrough reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251765(VS.80).aspx)